# Writing WHERE clause on Delta Lake History Tables

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to query the Delta Lake table history as described at the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/history

When I describe the delta table as follows

```
describe history '/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1'
```

I get the below table output

| version | timestamp | userId | userName | operation | operationParameters | job | notebook | clusterId | readVersion | isolationLevel | isBlindAppend | operationMetrics | userMetadata | engineInfo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2 | 18/03/2023 12:25:54.0000000 | 615257000000000 | carlton@olvin.com | MERGE | {""predicate"":""(s.primary_key_hash = t.primary_key_hash)"",""matchedPredicates"":""[{""predicate"":""(NOT (s.change_key_hash = t.change_key_hash))"",""actionType"":""update""}]"",""notMatchedPredicates"":""[{""actionType"":""insert""}]"",""notMatchedBySourcePredicates"":""[{""actionType"":""delete""}]""} | (null) | {""notebookId"":""3807690121522291""} | 0318-105603-oyrrx3xc | 1 | WriteSerializable | False | {""numTargetRowsCopied"":""0"",""numTargetRowsDeleted"":""1"",""numTargetFilesAdded"":""1"",""numTargetBytesAdded"":""9070"",""numTargetBytesRemoved"":""9176"",""numTargetDeletionVectorsAdded"":""0"",""numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated"":""27"",""executionTimeMs"":""13999"",""numTargetRowsInserted"":""0"",""numTargetRowsMatchedDeleted"":""0"",""scanTimeMs"":""4276"",""numTargetRowsUpdated"":""27"",""numOutputRows"":""27"",""numTargetDeletionVectorsRemoved"":""0"",""numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceUpdated"":""0"",""numTargetChangeFilesAdded"":""0"",""numSourceRows"":""27"",""numTargetFilesRemoved"":""1"",""numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceDeleted"":""1"",""rewriteTimeMs"":""9012""} | (null) | Databricks-Runtime/12.2.x-scala2.12" |
| "1 | 18/03/2023 12:14:43.0000000 | 615257000000000 | carlton@olvin.com | MERGE | {""predicate"":""(s.primary_key_hash = t.primary_key_hash)"",""matchedPredicates"":""[{""predicate"":""(NOT (s.change_key_hash = t.change_key_hash))"",""actionType"":""update""}]"",""notMatchedPredicates"":""[{""actionType"":""insert""}]"",""notMatchedBySourcePredicates"":""[{""actionType"":""delete""}]""} | (null) | {""notebookId"":""3807690121522291""} | 0318-105603-oyrrx3xc | 0 | WriteSerializable | False | {""numTargetRowsCopied"":""0"",""numTargetRowsDeleted"":""0"",""numTargetFilesAdded"":""1"",""numTargetBytesAdded"":""9176"",""numTargetBytesRemoved"":""0"",""numTargetDeletionVectorsAdded"":""0"",""numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated"":""0"",""executionTimeMs"":""6222"",""numTargetRowsInserted"":""28"",""numTargetRowsMatchedDeleted"":""0"",""scanTimeMs"":""2280"",""numTargetRowsUpdated"":""0"",""numOutputRows"":""28"",""numTargetDeletionVectorsRemoved"":""0"",""numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceUpdated"":""0"",""numTargetChangeFilesAdded"":""0"",""numSourceRows"":""28"",""numTargetFilesRemoved"":""0"",""numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceDeleted"":""0"",""rewriteTimeMs"":""3593""} | (null) | Databricks-Runtime/12.2.x-scala2.12" |
| "0 | 18/03/2023 12:14:23.0000000 | 615257000000000 | carlton@olvin.com | CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE | {""isManaged"":""false"",""description"":null,""partitionBy"":""[]"",""properties"":""{}""} | (null) | {""notebookId"":""3807690121522291""} | 0318-105603-oyrrx3xc | (null) | WriteSerializable | True | {} | (null) | Databricks-Runtime/12.2.x-scala2.12" |

I have assigned the path with the following variable

```
saveloc = '/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1'
```

As you can see from the History Output above there is field called **version** and **operationParameters**

Its easy to get the latest version from the history table with the following code:

```
df4 = spark.read.option("versionAsof", 3).load(saveloc)
```

There are various ways to get the latest version such as:

```
df5 = spark.read.load("/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1@v3")

Or

df6 = df5 = spark.read.load(saveloc+"@v3")

Or in SQL it would be something similar to:

SELECT * FROM saveloc@v3
```

Can someone let me know if it's possible to write a WHERE clause on the version field e.g

```
Select * From saveloc
where version > 2
```

Comment: The sample table doesn't appear to appearing as it should. Sorry about that

Comment: Side note re. Markdown table formatting for your question: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from deltatable version as of 9
```

Comment: Hi @John Stud, thanks for reaching out. Is there where of select the latest version without actually having to write ```select * from deltatable version as of 9```

Comment: Hi, I meant to say is there a WAY of selecting the version number without specifically specifying the version number .. e.g ```where version as of > 5```

Comment: If it's not possible to select the version number with a WHERE clause, can someone let me know if its possible to select the TIMESTAMP of the History table without actually specifying the actual TIMESTAMP e.g ```where timestamp between date1 and date2```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Let's imagine you have a table with 5 versions. If you use a query like

```
Select * From saveloc
where version > 2
```

which version would you expect to see, 3, 4 or 5?
You need to specify a version.

Comment: Hi @Robert, thanks for reaching out. The ultimate goal is to compare the latest version with a version just below the latest version e.g I would want to compare, say version 5 with version 4. But I don't want to have to actually specify version 5. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can run a select * from deltatable union select * from deltatable version as of 4 as when you do not specify the version you get the latest version.